# How to create a keystream generator in C for simple XOR cipher?

Tags: c, encryption, cryptography, key, key-generator

I am trying to create a **keystream generator** in C in order to encrypt some data with the generated key. This is for educational purposes.

> In cryptography, a keystream is a stream of random or pseudorandom
>   characters that are combined with a plaintext message to produce an
>   encrypted message

There is a little or no information online that explains the internal functioning of a keystream generator. So, what is the proper way to create a keystream generator?

Comment: *There is a little or no information online that explains the internal functioning of a keystream generator.* - I don't buy it. If there is no info online, buy a cryptography textbook. Stream ciphers are covered in the first few chapters in most cases. Not related to C by the way and too broad for SO.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Be kind. Do your research before you comment something like that. Unfortunately, currently, I have no access to cryptography books. If I did, I'd try to find an answer there before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NIST has described a key stream generator based on AES (in counter/CTR) in [NIST SP 800-38A](https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/detail/sp/800-38a/final).

Writing good key stream generators is hard, and pure stream ciphers have fallen into disuse because they do not sufficiently protect message integrity.